# Lost eth0 in latest update

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, ethernet

As someone who works in tech support, I understand that you lot are quite familiar with this opening, but, I'm frustrated.

Firstly, Google search results lead me to managed network devices problems. These solutions refer to a path that does not exist on my Ubuntu installation*. (/usr/lib/NetworkManager/**conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf** bold text is what's non-existent)

Secondly, lspci clearly defines the Ethernet device, so I know Ubuntu sees it

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device e0b1 (rev 10)
```

Thirdly, sudo ifconfig eth0 up returns No such device, with ifconfig alone returning just the loopback. Further, as I saw in a similar issue thread, **lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3** returns

```
02:00 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [1969:e0b1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co,. Ltd Device [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
```

Finally, just rebooted. Still definitely without internet. Unfortunately no wifi or alternative Ethernet devices available.

*Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS 64-Bit. Intel Core i3-6100. 7.7GB memory.

Edit: output of ifconfig -a shows:

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:1b:0d:97:82:79  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:43192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:3227412 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:3227412 (3.2 MB)
```

which shows my ethernet device. I tried *sudo ifconfig enp2s0 up* but that returned nothing with no results (Network Manager still showed no devices/connectivity)

Comment: What does `ifconfig -a` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out the problem. Going to mark this as solved after making this comment:
Thanks to Thomas Ward asking what the output of ifconfig -a was, **I determined that eth0 is enp2s0**. Some more google searching and I determined that my problem was DNS. Or rather, a lack thereof. **Ubuntu's network manager is having problems getting DNS addresses**. So I was able to fix this problem by adding google's DNS servers to the network profile.
8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
Then restarting network manager (sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service) and I now have internet. Further thanks to wildmanne39 of the ubuntu forums for [details on Ubuntu Network Manager's problems with DNS](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358720&p=13635196#post13635196)

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Comment: You bet. I'm no DenverCoder9 ;)